# Map of any type without Casts

Tags: c++, dictionary, templates, casting, any

Is there any way to have a map of different types without casting? I don't mean `std::map` or `boost::map`, I mean my own implementation without casting. I don't want to use `boost::any` or `std::any`, something like `std::variant` if it doesn't use casting. I am open to templates or any other fast (no casting) solution.

Would this work:

```
#define Args double, int, std::vector<double>, std::shared_ptr<double>

class ugly_map_uppearing_nice final
{
public:
    template<typename T>
    void get_ref_risky(const std::string& name, T* t)
    {
        //it = find... it!=end, it->... + get
        // some checks...
        t = &std::get<T>(m_imp[name]);
    };

private:
    std::map<std::string, std::variant<Args>> m_imp;
};
```

Comment: "fast (no casting) solution" looks like you started your question with delusion that casting is slow.

Comment: I don't know exactly how casting work, but that's what "THEY" told me!

Comment: Casting won't be any slower than any other mechanism you (or I) could devise.  Can you use polymorphism to wrap your types?  (Which you'll still need *some* sort of casting to unwrap your wrapped type.)

Comment: Then probably you should learn how casting works before making "no casting" as a requirement

Comment: Do you think I can use casting on real time application ticking every millisecond or less? I have to transfer messages of different types (like a system event). Please someone confirms I can. If yes, the I just go with `boost::any`?

Comment: `boost::any` / `std::any` will carry a significant performance overhead.  It would be better to use `boost::variant` or `std::variant` - read up on it, it's actually very powerful.

Comment: Most casts are done at compile time only, so they cannot possibly have impact on runtime. `dynamic_cast` has some runtime checks, but still, it probably won't be noticeable unless done in a tight loop (certainly it shouldn't take a millisecond). `std::any` or `boost::any` are likely to be worse performence-wise, because they need to use type-erasure techniques.

Comment: A millisecond is an eternity, don't worry about it. Ultimately, the only way to do this "without casts" is to cleverly hide the casts behind a bunch of templates, which won't help performance.

Comment: @Paul Sanders `std::variant` is not generic for a map no? Please see my answer for the response below, this is supposed to be at the developer level, it's up to the user to define the type, my map has to handle it. `std::variant` will definitly need the ***limited** number of types at compile time. Or you talking about something fancier by using `template<typename...Args>` and all?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat how please? I am ready to have ugly code as long as it's fast? (Ah sorry I am editting my response: You are saying it won't help performace) Thanks anyway

Comment: You asked for "no casting" 4 times in your question, but that is completely incompatible with homogenous use of different types, unless you template the entire code base that would use that "map" or be used by it and instantiate it for each possible type. But that presents another challenge, since it seems you also have a requirement that the "map" be compatible with an unspecified set of types.

Comment: C++ is a strongly-typed language. The type of every object must be known at compile time. This is absolute, there are no exceptions to this rule. Your choices are to use either `std::any`, and attempt to guess at the type that's been erased, by `std::any`, or use `std::variant`. There are no other type-safe alternatives.

Comment: @Vero Your map implementation should be a class template (is it?)  Then, many things become possible.

Comment: What do you want to do with this map? Show some use cases.

Comment: Same example as in one of my previous questions, map will hold details of a request e.g. Request: How many followers does Elon Musk have Map (Response) is just string to int. Other Request could be what was the temperature in the last 10 days Map in this case is Map from String to Vector of Doubles and other requests  could have replies that might be new objects :)

Comment: @Paul Sanders Could you please check my question on top, I added an option, is that what you have in mind. I am null in Parameter pack template thing, tried once and just let go, it's not simple but if you think possible I definitly will give it a shot

Comment: Kindof.  Creating a `std::map` that can hold the type of `std::variant` that you want is what I was driving at, yes, but the rest doesn't look right at all.  You're struggling here, I think you need to do some background reading.  For a curated list of C++ books, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list.  There should be something there that will help you improve your skillset.  Also, online compilers are a great way to experiment.  Personally, I like [Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/), but there are several others.

Comment: And please bear in mind that SO is not a tutorial site.  It's a Q&A site that is designed to answer tightly focussed, well researched questions and you're not doing that, so there's a limit to what we can do for you here as things stand.  When you have a better understanding of what it is you're trying to achieve, and of the tools that C++ has to offer, you should have better luck.

Comment: "How many followers does Elon Musk have" doesn't look like C++ code. Show how you want to use your map in a C++ program.

Comment: The question is clear without any example. How to have a map that holds any type.